# Per user code values in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project that I will release as open source, but it will have to contain some values (BASS audio library freeware regkey, url for update server, etc.) that I only want to be compiled into the source when compiling it for a binary release for those people that just want to use the application and do not care about the source.  Basically, I want to prevent people who use the source code from using my reg key (they can get their own for free) or having their version contact my update server since versions will be different.

So, what's the best way to make something that will be compiled into the code and used if the file exists, but I could then exclude from source control and it would just use defaults or disable compilation of certain sections if that file does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the project file to conditionally include either one file or another based on the build type. I don't have a sample to hand, but it shouldn't be too hard to do. *Something* like:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <Compile Include="PublicFile.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'ApplicationRelease' ">
  <Compile Include="PrivateFile.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I would try to structure the "library" part separately from the "application" part, and always make the library part take the relevant parameters in its configuration. That way anyone *just* wanting to use the library should be able to use a "release" DLL - it's only the application which needs the extra file before it'll work.

EDIT: It's entirely possible that the same approach will work with `app.config` if you want to include the values in a config file instead.

Comment: Awesome, looks easy enough.  Will give it a try.  Fortunately, I already created the libraries so that if they are initialized with the values they will use them, otherwise they handle it appropriately, and all the values are passed in at the application level.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adam: I would definitely refactor that to pass them in whatever the situation. It's a cleaner design.

Comment: No sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Adam: I would expect the libraries to *always* expect the values to be passed in. How else can they operate?

Comment: Oh, yeah... the way they are setup right now, if a value for the registration key is passed in, it will use it, but if that value is empty it will just not register.  It still works, but BASS flashes a trial screen if you don't provide the key.  I was basically trying to avoid breaking the build if the value is not provided so that people don't have to go out and get all those values first.  If you have a suggestion for a better way to handle that, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Adam: If it's just a matter of flashing a trial screen, that's not so bad I guess...

Comment: yeah... I just figured they can set that up later if they wanted, I just know I always find it really annoying when source code I download doesn't compile out of the box.  And the only other thing this concerns is contacting *my* update server which, while they can setup their own if they want to create a fork of my app, I don't want them accessing mine at all...

Answer (score 1):

How I would go about doing this:

1. Place the variable elements into the app.config file and in your source control have default values.
2. Have the application load the values from app.config
3. Either include instructions on how to change the defaults, or have a small wrapper that updates the defaults the first time the app is run (for situations where potential users would not have the knowledge to edit app.config).